# Can I set the schedule for automatic Market updates, e.g. every night?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate, automation

Is there a way to schedule when the Market updates my installed apps? Ideally I would like to run it late every night, that way I won't have to be bothered with them when I'm actually using the phone.

Comment: Great question Suan.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts lately.  It always updates right when I'm playing a certain game, and the game stutters and pauses repeatedly during that time.  I can't believe this still isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but maybe [tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can do it. If it can't do it directly and if you are rooted, you can use  tasker to kill Market except on night time. That way at night time Market will run and install your apps. At day time market will get killed and no installing of apps.

Comment: Doesn't this also prevent one from using the Market oneself? The Tasker function has to be disabled for Market to work.

Comment: Yes it would. But you can create tasker profile like check every 30 mins in day time if market is running and kill it if its. In these way You can use Market as well and hopefully apps won't update in that 30 mins period.

Comment: I'm wondering if one would be able to write an app, which basically opens up the Market app at a set time, and even better somehow forcing it to "update"...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Market to only update apps when its connected to Wi-Fi. If you only ever connect your device to Wi-Fi at home, then this setting could do the trick for you?

**Market** -> <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> **Settings** -> **Update over Wi-Fi only**

---

**Update**: Bringing in info from the comments by [Mr. Buster](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/11343/mr-buster) and [Power-Inside](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/5501/power-inside):

It seems that the "Update over Wifi only" setting was only [added to the Market app in v3.3.11](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/01/download-android-market-3-3-11-adds-new-settings-default-auto-update-update-over-wi-fi-only-shortcuts-and-more/). If your Market app is stuck on an older version then you can try to force an update by clearing the data on the Market app, or manually download and install an updated Market APK, as detailed in [this previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18948/cyanogenmod-why-doesnt-market-self-upgrade/18949#18949).

Comment: I personally cannot find such an option.

Comment: It's in the Market settings for me, and has been for a while (currently on Market v3.4.4 on a Gingerbread Galaxy S)

Comment: @Boris_yo what device and version of android are you using? You really should state these things in the question :)

Comment: HTC Desire S, Android 2.3.3, Market 2.3.4

Comment: @Boris_yo: best I can tell, the _Update over Wi-Fi only_ setting came along around Market v3.3.11. For this feature you'll need to get Market updated.

Comment: But my Market never updated itself or asked to be updated.

Comment: @Boris_yo [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/18949/5501) might be of some help to get an upgraded market.

Comment: Upgraded or updated? And how do i do that?

Comment: The "update over WiFi only" setting doesn't help the issue when you're connected to slow hotel WiFi and the updates take up what little bandwidth is available.

Comment: @cragmonkey for that you have the options that restrict background data usage. Go into Settings then Data Usage, then click the menu option and select Network Restrictions, you can then find your slow wi-fi connection in the list and select it to set it as a "metered connection"which will make Android test that connection as if it's metered and it will turn off background data usage and app updates while you're on there.

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no such functionality in Market. You can set for "auto update" on all your apps, but you cannot specify when they get updated.

Comment: He didn't ask if the Market featured this, just if there was some way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to do this but there are other ways to 'control' the updates. You can disable auto-updating, or only via Wifi from settings. You could also force stop the Play store app and then later in the day when you are connected to Wifi and not using your device, you open the app again and it installs updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** I disabled the *Auto updates* completely and set up a reminder which pops up twice every week at 10 pm when I'm not using my phone and enable the *Auto updates* until I go to bed.