# Why Automatic App Updates In Market Don't Work?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

Every time i see a few of apps trying to auto-update themselves but just stalling when it says "Downloading". In other words, automatic update for apps does not work and I am only left with cancelling download/update and doing this manually.

Is there a reason why automatic updates do not work?

Additionally it would be good to know if there was a way to schedule updating of apps or somehow to update a few at one time because updating many/most apps after accessing internet after a long period of time just bogs down system.

Comment: Also experience this on the HTC Sensation with Android 2.3.4 and have done since the phone came out.  I've seen it work on other Androids with a different version of the market to what we have.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with permissions?

Comment: Fro the scheduling aspect of your question, see this other question [Can I set the schedule for automatic Market updates, e.g. every night?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14218/)

Comment: It is CyanogenMod and i don't have that. Since i bought smartphone, i never rooted or changed to other mods and to this day i still use Android 2.3.3 that came with it.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if the download cache is full or nearly full, and the download would fill your internal storage.  Try cleaning out your caches to free up some space (SD Maid is a good free app for this) and seeing if the downloads will complete then.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen problems when I don't have WiFi on for a while.  Some updates are marked as WiFi-only due to the large size, even if you have turned off "Update over Wi-Fi only" in the Market settings (which I assume you have unchecked).

I think there may be other quirks with the Market app.  For example, if you are in airplane mode but have WiFi on, the Market may think you're offline and refuse to work.

It may (or may not) help to switch between having auto-update on globally (in Market settings) vs. having it off but enabling auto-update for individual apps.

BTW I just enable auto-update for apps that I trust and know I won't read the update log for before accepting the update.

Comment: I don't have such setting in my Market v2.3.4

Comment: You mean that your phone is Android 2.3.4, right?  You'll find these settings while in the market app by pressing menu, then settings.  You'll also see the version of the market app on the settings screen, called the "build version", which will be in the neighborhood of 3.4.4.

Comment: No my phone has Android 2.3.3 But i will try upgrading to Police Market. By the way can i reverse to previous version in case something is wrong?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to downgrade, unless you have a saved copy of the market app.  That is likely more effort than you're interested in.

Comment: How do i backup Android Market app? All i have found in **system/app** folder is MarketUpdater.apk

Comment: Look into Astro File manager or Titanium Backup.

Comment: @ProjectJourneyman The OP and I seemed to be on an older version of market (the mainly green one), mine has updated itself in the past few days, with no warning or confirmation I might add!  Hoping the OP is as lucky and will get the update soon.

Comment: @RichardBenson Your updated itself recently? To which version? Mine did not update itself for a long time if not since smartphone's purchase.

Comment: @Boris_yo updated itself again to "Play Shop" yesterday, version 3.4.6

Comment: @RichardBenson What is "Play Shop"?

Comment: @Boris_yo is Google's fancy new marketing term for the market! market.android.com now redirects to play.google.com